# Does AVG security toolbar do anything useful actually?

Tags: anti-virus, toolbar, avg-antivirus

Does AVG security toolbar do anything useful actually? It seems to me that all its functionality is already integrated into Linkscanner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linkscanner is a resource hog. It sucks your computers cpu power and internet bandwith since it scans every search results you get from google. I´d say AVG´s toolbar AND Linkscanner both are useless.

Comment: So, it does so without you clicking on it? That would even reveal your IP address to that web site then, just because some search engine showed it to you. If true, then that's a HUGE privacy fail, I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

AVG Security Toolbar could prevent you from accessing a phishing/malware-site. But I don't see sense in such tools, if the user is smart enough to think, before he clicks...

Comment: Also all modern browsers and even Google implements this natively.

Answer (score 1):

I would just close the tool bar. AVG will still be running. The linkscanner should be enough. I think it is just another annoying tool bar. Close the bar won't end the process, so you should still be fully protected.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have the latest browser versions, the toolbar is pretty much useless, it had its place before the updates to the browsers for the malware and spoof sites.

Answer (score 0):

Since the search field has been integrated in most browsers, I don't see a need for the most conventional toolbars out there. The security-related ones will only add some annoying icons to search pages and display something if it thinks a site can't be trusted, but the users that will visit these sites usually ignore warnings altogether, unless you block their screen for a minute and force them to read and think about it.